# Update existing default parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, default-value

In javascript, is it possible to update the value of a default parameter on an existing function?

Suppose I've got:

```
function addNumbers(a, b=2) {
    return a+b;
}
```

and later in my program I'd like to update the default value of `b` so if someone calls `addNumbers` with only one argument `b` now defaults to something else, but if they call `addNumbers` with two arguments, both of those arguments are still used.

If such a thing is possible, how would you do it?

**Edit:**

I know it's possible if the original function uses a global variable for the default value like so:

```
let defaultB = 2;
function addNumbers(a, b=defaultB) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Then any updates to `defaultB` will update the default for `b`. Does anyone know a way to do it without globals?

Comment: `let o = { p: 0 }; function f(a = o.p) { console.log(a); }; f(); o.p = "new"; f();` seems to work. I forgot, that default parameters load the old scope, actually get executed as code every time, before executing the actual function.

Comment: Thanks @ASDFGerte. Doing it with some sort of global value was all I could come up with as well. I was hoping there was a solution that didn't use globals, but that's on me for not specifying that.

Comment: It doesnt need to be global, you can e.g. make it a property of the function itself, or store it in any other non-global way, as long as you have access to it, when you want to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable or a property instead of the literal, e.g

```js
function addNumbers(a, b=addNumbers.b) {
    return a+b;
}
addNumbers.b = 2;

console.log(addNumbers(5))

addNumbers.b = 100;

console.log(addNumbers(5))
```

I'm not sure what practical use this might have except to confuse someone.